# Why using scala parallelism have slower performance in this case?

Tags: java, scala

The class TestClassString returns a java.util.List of Strings

The object TestViewPerformance records the time taken to call method TestViewController.iterateList.

Within iterateList the time taken to run this small program is consistently at least 100ms faster when parallelism is removed :

mySeq.par
to
mySeq

I realise there is benchmarking tool used for measuring scala performance as specified here : 
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/performance.html

But still I would expect this program to run faster using parallelism based on current millisecond time ? Is all code within the .par loop spread over multiple cores ?

Here is the entire code :

```
package testpackage

import java.util.Calendar

object TestViewPerformance {

  def main(args:Array[String]) = {

      val before = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()

      val testViewController = new TestViewController();
      val testClassString : TestClassString = new TestClassString()

      val folderList = testClassString.getStringList()
      var buffer = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
      val seq = scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(folderList);

      /*
       * this method (iterateList) is where the parallelism occurs
       */
      testViewController.iterateList(seq)

      val after = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()

      println(before)
      println(after)
      println(after-before)

  }

  class TestViewController {

      def iterateList(mySeq : Seq[String]) = {

        for (seqVal<- mySeq) {
            if(seqVal.equalsIgnoreCase("test")){            

            }
        }   
}

}

}

package testpackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClassString {

    public List<String> getStringList(){

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){
            String test = ""+Math.random();
            l.add(test);
        } 

        return l;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because most of the time in each iteration is spent printing to `System.out`, which is a synchronized operation that is thus not parallelizable. So the cost induced by starting threads, scheduling them and synchronize them makes the parallel iteration slower than the sequential one.

Comment: ive removed the println but same result, the 'if condition' is never true.

Comment: Make each iteration do something substantial (or sleep for some time). Comparing two strings which always differ at their length or first character is so fast that parallelizing it on 1,000,000 instances won't bring any performance gain.

Answer (score 8):

Because your benchmark is measuring overhead of thread switching and quantum fluctuations. Add at least `Thread.sleep(1)` to your loop and see what happens:

```
scala> val strings = (1 to 10000).map(_ + Math.random().toString)
strings: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(10.8907863042670979, 20.2871957696184603, 30.20011325237932742, 40.7490949002788928, 50.5073228980632211...
scala> val time = System.currentTimeMillis; 
       | for (str <- strings.par) {Thread.sleep(1)}; 
       | System.currentTimeMillis - time
res0: Long = 1398

scala> val time = System.currentTimeMillis; 
       | for (str <- strings) {Thread.sleep(1)}; 
       | System.currentTimeMillis - time
res3: Long = 11129
```

Comment: adding a Thread.sleep(1) does make it run faster. I'm confused as to why though. In production there will be no 'Thread.sleep' used, does this mean I should not use .par since it seems to run faster without it ?

Comment: @user470184: in production you will have some processing, and it may take more than a millisecond. You have to understand that parallel collections induce some overhead to split tasks into threads, to manage them all etc. So if whatever processing you're doing in the loop is smaller than this overhead, it is not worth using par.